# I can't choose UTF-8 in Run Configurations in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, encoding

I want my output console to use UTF-8. All the resources I've found online have told me to go to Run Configurations->(target configuration)->Common, and then select UTF-8 from the dropdown in the Encoding panel.

I can't interact with anything in the Encoding panel. I can't select the radio button next to "Default", and nothing happens when I click on the dropdown list.

(Actually, I just noticed the only thing I can interact with at all in the Common tab are the check boxes in the "Display in favorites menu" selection.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'radio button' in the Encoding panel is not actually a radio button. Click to the left of 'Other'. This will move the selector to the appropriate line, so you may interact with the dropdown menu. Similarly for the other items on the page, there is an open space next to them where you may click to activate.